# EGOPhotoViewer and NavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm having a problem with EGOPhotoView library in my iOS app, and I hope someone of you can help me.

My app uses a NavigationController, but does not display the NavigationBar, because the navigation is managed my some custom control. The problem is when I show an image gallery with the EGOPhotoView library, which shows a NavigationBar appearing on tap: when I pop the EGOPhotoViewController, the NavigationBar is still displayed, but I don't want.

Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set one of your classes (probably your app delegate) to be the navigation controller's delegate. Then, when the EGOPhotoViewController is popped, you can hide the navigation bar. E.g.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[EGOPhotoViewController class]])
    {
        [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```